# Bash searches for inexistent directories upon opening terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

I tried to install IRAF a couple weeks ago but I couldn't get it to work so I ended up uninstalling the whole thing. Ever since, whenever I open my terminal I get this:

```
bash: /home/ani/iraf//unix/hlib/irafarch.sh: Not a directory
bash: /home/ani/iraf//unix/hlib/irafuser.sh: Not a directory
ani@Jinx:~$
```

It hasn't caused me any trouble, but I'm guessing I've accidentally altered something somewhere but I can't figure out what it is that's causing this. Any suggestions?

**EDIT** 
grep iraf ~/.bash* gives me the following:

```
ani@Jinx:~$ grep iraf ~/.bash*
...
/home/ani/.bash_login:# Add iraf setup commands
/home/ani/.bash_login:if [ -e /home/ani/.iraf/setup.sh ]; then
/home/ani/.bash_login:    source /home/ani/.iraf/setup.sh
/home/ani/.bash_profile:# Add iraf setup commands
/home/ani/.bash_profile:if [ -e /home/ani/.iraf/setup.sh ]; then
/home/ani/.bash_profile:    source /home/ani/.iraf/setup.sh
/home/ani/.bashrc:# Add iraf setup commands
/home/ani/.bashrc:if [ -e /home/ani/.iraf/setup.sh ]; then
/home/ani/.bashrc:    source /home/ani/.iraf/setup.sh
```

Comment: what does `grep iraf ~/.bash*` show you?

Comment: i edited the question with the results since they were too long to comment

Comment: What is inside `/home/ani/.iraf/setup.sh`?

Comment: #!/bin/bash  

# Allow a previously defined $iraf to be used.  
if [ -n $iraf ]; then  
    export iraf=/home/ani/iraf/  
fi  

# Allow a previously defined $IRAFARCH to be used.  
if [ -n $IRAFARCH ]; then  
    export IRAFARCH=`$iraf/unix/hlib/irafarch.sh -actual`  
fi  
source $iraf/unix/hlib/irafuser.sh  

export PATH=$HOME/.iraf/bin:${PATH}

Comment: (Sorry, I can't get the hang of commenting just yet)

Comment: I removed .bash_history since that is not needed. Makes it better to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove these lines in `/home/ani/.bashrc`:

```
# Add iraf setup commands
if [ -e /home/ani/.iraf/setup.sh ]; then
source /home/ani/.iraf/setup.sh
```

You can do this command line with

```
vi /home/ani.bashrc
```

scroll down to "# Add iraf setup commands" and press `esc` once and `dd` 3 times. `:wq!` to save.

---

Same goes for the files `/home/ani/.bash_login` and `/home/ani/.bash_profile`.

---

By the way: the way this command is set up I would assume that `/home/ani/.iraf/` exists. You probably also need to do a `rm -r /home/ani/.iraf/` to remove the hidden directory `iraf`. If you only do this the commands in those 3 files will skip the sourcing of the setup file. But you'd still have junk in those files.